# How to populate IEnumerable data to dropdownlist for nested view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate my categories to dropdownlist. When user select a category, I will call an ajax function and show partial view about selected item. Even though I can populate category names, I cannot add respective values of each category.
Generated Html:

```
<select class="test" id="myDropDown" name="filterName"><option value="">
Select a category</option>
<option>Games</option>
<option>Business</option>
<option>Life</option>
<option>Health</option>
<option>Education</option>
<option>Music</option>
<option>Media</option>
```

My view model:

```
namespace CETAPPSUGG.Models
{
  public class HomeCombinedModel
    {

    public IEnumerable<Apps> Apps { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubCatagories> SubCategories { get; set; }


    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var apps = db.Apps.Include(a => a.Categories).Include(a => a.SubCatagories).Include(a => a.ApplicationUser);
            var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
            var subcategories = db.SubCatagories.ToList();


            HomeCombinedModel deneme = new HomeCombinedModel();

            deneme.Apps = apps.ToList();
            deneme.Categories = categories;
            deneme.SubCategories = subcategories;
            return View(deneme);


        }
```

My View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("filterName", new SelectList(Model.Categories.Select(i => i.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList()), "Select a category", new {id = "myDropDown", @class = "test" })

     @Html.DropDownListFor(
    Model.Categories.Select(i => i.Id)
    new SelectList(Model.Categories.Select(i => i.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList()))
```

The problem is in my view. How can i populate my items with their id values to dropdownlist. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an IEnumerable of type `SelectListItem`.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatesList()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text="", Value=null },
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Alabama", Value="AL"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Alaska", Value="AK"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Arizona", Value="AZ"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Arkansas", Value="AR"},
    };
    return list;
}
```

Then just add your drop down list to your form like so.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Address.State, Model.StatesList())
```

You can dynamically generate your SelectListItems using your existing lists.

EDIT - Here is a more detailed example.

```
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CatagoriesSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach(Category c in Categories)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = c.Key,
                    Value = c.Value
                });
            }

            return list;
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

In this particular example, you'll need to have a temporary attribute in your custom class, and then when you POST your model, map that to the corresponding Category and update that value.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I added public List<Categories> CategoryList()
        {
            return Categories.ToList();
        } this code to controller.  But in my view     @Html.DropDownListFor( Model => Model.Categories, Model.CategoryList())
 there is still problem ?

Comment: What I was suggesting was to generate a list of selectlistitems, not OF categories but rather FROM categories...if that makes sense.  I don't understand what you're saying exactly.

Comment: By the way, SelectListItem is a predefined class in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering  - This reference is defaulted in all views.  Just add the reference to it in your class that contains your List<Categories> and follow the example I provided in the edit above.